# .BRD and .MIX files that get deleted. Creating them

Tags: shell-script

I'm running a BBS. A software I ported from DOS to Linux. Impulse BBS. I'm having problems with the message base files. The problem is, it deletes the `.BRD` files, for some reason, and that halts the system. And crashes the BBS. I need to figure out a way to create those `.BRD` files when missing. Here's a script I wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash

inotifywait --daemon --outfile /home/imp/imp/test.log -m /home/imp/imp/msgs -e create 
while read path action file; do
    echo "The file '$file' appeared in directory '$path' via '$action'"
    for name in /home/imp/imp/msgs/*.MIX; do
            touch "${name}.BRD"
    done
done
```

It doesn't appear to be working, though. It does not actually `touch` the `.BRD` file(s). These `.BRD` files can be 0-byte length in size. I'm using `inotifywait` because it seems to be the best way to address this situation. I have other scripts that utilitze `inotifywait`, and they suit my needs perfectly.

Comment: I doubt may of us know what these files are supposed to be, or how to create them, without you telling us what software it is that uses them. As the question currently stands, it is unclear what it is you want to achieve (apart from creating files that we know nothing about).

Comment: They can be 0-byte length files. A simple `touch AGN_SYS.BRD` (for example) would work. They are message base files for a BBS system.

Comment: 1. create (or extract from the source code / configuration files) a list of all such files that need to exist.  2. touch all files in that list.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little? Thanks.

Comment: (1) As Kusalananda says, you’ll get better answers if you ask a better question.  If it’s good enough to create zero-length file(s), you should say so *in the text of your question*.  Don’t explain your question in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.  And don’t force people to try to understand the code you’ve written just to figure out (i.e., guess) what you want to accomplish.  (1a) I *guess* that you’re saying that `.BRD` and `.MIX` files get created in pairs (e.g., `foo.BRD` and `foo.MIX`), and that sometimes,  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  mysteriously, one of them (only one?) gets deleted.  And that you want to recreate the deleted file (as a zero-length file) based on the name of the survivor.  If that’s your situation, *say so*, clearly, in the text of your question.  If that’s not the situation, explain the actual situation at the same level of clarity (or higher). (2) Why are you running `inotifywait`?  (Do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.) (3) What happens when you run your script?  Can you explain why?  Can you explain how the actual behavior  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  differs from the desired behavior?  Can you describe what needs to be done to the script to make it do what you want?  Where are you stuck? (4) It looks like you want the `while read` loop to monitor the output from `inotifywait`.  If that’s what you want, try running `inotifywait` without `--daemon` and `--outfile` *and **piping** it **into*** the `while read` loop. (5) If your `for name in` loop finds a `foo.MIX` file, it will touch `foo.MIX.BRD`.  I think that’s not what you want.  Can you fix it? (6) Don’t you also want to do ``for name in *.BRD; do touch "${name}.MIX"``?

Comment: You have already 2 reopen votes. Over 300 rep, also you will have a vote regarding your own questions. Good luck! I think your improvement deserves the reopen.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking too much at the `inotifywait` bit of your code, it looks as if the inner part of the loop touches a file based on what's in the `name` variable:

```
for name in /home/imp/imp/msgs/*.MIX; do
        touch "${name}.BRD"
done
```

The value of `$name` will be a pathname with a filename at the end that has the `.MIX` filename suffix.

Touching `$name.BRD` will create a file with a `.MIX.BRD` filename suffix, whereas I *believe* that you might want the original `.MIX` suffix *replaced* by `.BRD`.

This does that:

```
for name in /home/imp/imp/msgs/*.MIX; do
        touch "${name%.MIX}.BRD"
done
```

`${name%.MIX}` removes `.MIX` from the end of the value of `$name`.

The code probably also lacks a `|` at the end of the `inotifywait` command, to be able to feed its output into the `while read` loop:

```
#!/bin/sh

inotifywait --daemon --outfile /home/imp/imp/test.log -m /home/imp/imp/msgs -e create |
while read path action file; do
    printf 'The file "%s" appeared in directory "%s" via "%s"\n' "$file" "$path" "$action"

    for name in "$path"/*.MIX; do
            touch "${name%.MIX}.BRD"
    done
done
```

Here, I've also taken the liberty to change the `echo` to a `printf` (as it's outputting variable data), and of using `$path` in the inner `for` loop, which I hope is correct. The code doesn't use any special `bash` features, so I've changed the shell to `/bin/sh` as well.

Depending on how `inotifywait` works and what `$file` is and what you want to do, it may be enough to touch a file based on `$file` rather than looping through all files in the directory.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. There is a problem with the code, though. On your `inotifywait` solution, it gives me this error: `./ren2.sh: 11: ./ren2.sh: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string`

Comment: @ignatius Huh. `$action"` was missing its initial `"`. I had to look at it three times before I spotted it :-) Now fixed. Thanks.

Comment: I'll test it first. If it works, then i'll accept the question as solved.

Comment: @ignatius Absolutely, if nobody comes with a better answer, obviously.